# Laravel bind object auth user in vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

How I can get auth user in app.js with vue?

I have:

```
<message v-for="value,index in chat.message" 
                :key=value.index 
                :user=chat.user[index]
                :message="chat.message[index]"
                :currentUser="{{ auth()->user() }}"
>
```

In app.js

```
    data:{
    message: '',
    currentUser: [],
    chat: {
        message: [],
        user: [],
        time: [],
    },
    typing: '',
    },
    ....
    mounted() {
       console.log(this.currentUser.name);
    }
```

I get undefined object. How I can send to vue object auth user?